# What distros are NOT affected by the new Code of Conduct?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, git

What distros of Linux or Unix based operating systems are NOT subject to the new code of conduct recently implemented for Linux? And/or which use no code affected by this CoC?
 
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8a104f8b5867c682d994ffa7a74093c54469c11f 
https://lulz.com/linux-devs-threaten-killswitch-coc-controversy-1252/ 
https://hub.packtpub.com/linux-programmers-opposed-to-new-code-of-conduct-threaten-to-pull-code-from-project/ 
I have asked this elsewhere and been called trolling, so just to clarify, I am GENUINELY interested in finding out which distros will not have essential code pulled out, rendering them useless. I am simply looking for a stable unix/linux based OS. I have been using A variation of ubuntu for years but as the above articles should explain, this is not trolling or spam, I have a genuine concern about the short and long term functionality of Linux based operating systems.

Comment: You're asking this under the assumption that claims in these threats are true to begin with. [SFC says they aren't.](https://lwn.net/Articles/766784/)

Comment: well that's reassuring, but for the sake of argument, if it were a feasible threat, what distros would be unaffected?

Comment: "_Is there a Linux distribution that doesn't use the Linux kernel?_"... am I understanding you correctly?...

Comment: @Attie, that actually isn't so off-the-wall.  Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_operating_system_kernels.  Several, like HURD and FreeBSD, are used in what would still be referred to as "Linux" distros.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code of Conduct document is real.  The initial "scare" about the world as we know it ending is not a likely scenario.  As grawity linked to in a comment, it looks like contributors don't have a legal basis to pull their code.  What will happen as a result of the CoC is anyone's guess.  It could still have a chilling effect, where some top contributers stop contributing.  Or, the CoC could end up being modified so that it is no longer an issue.  People can only speculate.  However, it could potentially affect Linux in some negative way, at least temporarily, which still leaves your question.

We can look at your question from the perspective that if something negative does happen as a result, would certain distros be unaffected, or less affected?

There are substantial differences in "classes" of distros.  At one extreme are bare bones operating systems, with little more than some basic tools and a terminal.  At the other extreme are distros that are intended to be a user-friendly work environment out of the box.

The world of Linux contains in the hundreds of thousand of modules of code.  Within each class of distro, each distro is like a menu at a Chinese restaurant, "two from column A and one from column B".  It is a selection from the available modules that enable each function to be accomplished; a kernel, a collection of hardware drivers, a package management system, a collection of system utilities, a user interface, maybe a bundle of applications software, and so on, plus all of the libraries and component modules all of those things depend on.  In a fully loaded distro, there can be in the thousands of code modules.

How you might be affected if one or more of those modules was affected depends on the module.  The module could relate to something you don't even use, or it could be central to your operating system, or anything in between.  We also can't predict the nature of the impact, or how it would be mitigated.

Because of the way most things in Linux are tested before release, if you stuck with stuff from the distro's repositories, you wouldn't likely experience critical failures.  Any fallout from the CoC would more likely manifest as slower availability of improvements and features, and perhaps fixes for existing bugs.

When you pick a distro, you first need to select a "class" or type.  If you're a pro, you might want a bare-bones distro that you specify and build yourself almost from the ground up.  If you're a novice, that isn't practical, so you need something much more complete and ready to use.

Once you define the class of distro you need, there are lots of alternatives to pick from.  But all of those qualifying distros will have more or less similar complexity in terms of the number of code modules they contain.

If we assume that whatever impact the CoC is going to have will be random, we can't predict what types of code modules will be affected, or which ones will be affected.  In a general sense, users of bare bones distros will have fewer code modules that could potentially be affected.  However, you can't really pick a distro on that basis; you need whatever level of functionality you need.  Within whatever class of distro is appropriate for your needs, they will all have similar risks.

Bottom line:

- No distro would be immune.
- Bare-bones distros have fewer code modules that could be affected, but that isn't likely a useful fact.
- Within whatever class of distro that will meet your functionality needs, all of the distros will have essentially the same degree of risk.
- Even worst case risks aren't likely to manifest in a way that would seriously affect you as an end user.